# add css per category heading - magento

Tags: css, magento

I am trying to add css background colour to each H1 within a category structure, so when you land on any page within the category they have the same colour background - problem is magento; unable to add a new class or id to the sections. or being able to target them as a sub

EG: nav 1 & its sub nav landing page H1 would be red background & Nav 2 & its sub nav H1 to be blue background

NAV 1 
     - sub nav1
     - sub nav2
     - sub nav3

NAV 2 
     - sub nav1
     - sub nav2
     - sub nav3

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento adds classes to the body tag so you should be able to target exactly:

```
.nav1.sub-nav1.sub-nav2 h1 { background:blue; } /* no spaces between classes */
.nav2.sub-nav1.sub-nav2 h1 { background:red; } /* no spaces between classes */
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you are having is targeting the items.  Try:

```
div:nth-child(1)
{
 background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(2)
{
 background: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g5sjx105/